# How can i run a method with multiple threads from action listener

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, thread-safety

JFrame with action listener when button is clicked GUI Freezes and opens blank white screen instead of my chess game

```
private static void createAndShowGui() {
frame = new JFrame();
frame.getContentPane().setForeground(new Color(153, 153, 153));
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(51, 51, 51));
frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 600);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
```

//when button is clicked gui frezze and method called does not work

```
btnSingle = new JButton("Single Player");
        btnSingle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                GamePlay.play(1);
            }
        });
}
```

//method from other class that starts the chess game works fine when called normally but not when called from GUI

```
public static void startGame(ChessPlayer p1, ChessPlayer p2,Board board) {


        p1.update(board);
        p2.update(board);

        ChessPlayer[] players = new ChessPlayer[2];
        players[1] = p1.getColor() == 1 ? p1 : p2;
        players[0] = p2.getColor() == 0 ? p2 : p1;
```

//infinite loop never exits
            while (true) {

```
            if(board.getCurrentColor() ==1)
                p1.start();
            else
                p2.start();

            if(board.getCurrentColor() ==0)
                p1.stop();
            else 
                p2.stop();

//waits for player to make move before executing
            PieceMove m = players[board.getCurrentColor()].makePieceMove(board);

            board.apply(m);
            p1.update(board);
            p2.update(board);

            if (board.checkMate(players[board.getCurrentColor()].getColor()) || p1.isTimeOut()) {
                if(players[board.getCurrentColor()].getColor()==1){
                    if(board.checkMate(players[board.getCurrentColor()].getColor())) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Checkmate, you Lose!  Player 2 - Black Wins!");

                    }
                    else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Player 2's timer ran out, You Win!!!");

                    }

                    p1.close();
                    p2.close();
                }
                else {
                    if(board.checkMate(players[board.getCurrentColor()].getColor())) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Checkmate, you Win!!! Player 2 - Black Loses!");

                    }
                    else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Timer ran out you lose!!  Player 2 - Black Wins!");

                    }
                    p1.close();
                    p2.close();
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest using a LayoutManager. They are there to make your life easier when you switch to different machines, different os's, etc. If you absolutely need to, it is better to make your own LayoutManager than to deal with a null one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the GamePlay was not started as a separate thread.

You have to derive gameplay from Runnable and overwrite the run method.

It looks like this:

```
public class GamePlay implements Runnable {
   public GamePlay(int param){
      // init your settings here
   }

   public void play(){
      // start Game here
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      play();
   }
}
```

To start the game a new thread must be created.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   // generate Game
   GamePlay game = new GamePlay(1);
   // generate Thread
   Thread thread = new Thread(game);
   // run thread
   thread.run();
}
```